# Changing matched output of grep using sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with the following

```
           <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="red">
            <article>
                                                            <h1>Some unique text</h1>
          
           <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="red">
            <article>
                                                            <h1>More unique text</h1>

           <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="red">
            <article>
                                                            <h1>Even more unique text</h1>
```

I need to be able change the colour value before a specific string i.e

search for "More unique text" and replace the colour red to orange so the output is

```
            <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="orange">
             <article>
                                                            <h1>More unique text</h1>
```

and the other colour values are left as red.

I can get the colour in the line i want to change using

```
grep -B 2 "More unique text" file | sed -e '2,4d'
```

which returns

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="red">
```

But how do i change the value red to orange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml parser like `xmlstarlet` is better suited to parse xml/html. If your input strictly follows the rules mentioned in your question, you can use

```sh
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/class="\Kred(?=".*\n.*\n.*More unique text)/orange/'
```

- `-i` for inplace editing
- `-0777` to slurp entire input as single string, so this isn't suited for large input files
- `class="\K` match `class="` but don't include it as part of matched text
- `red` text to match
- `(?=".*\n.*\n.*More unique text)` match `"` and check if `More unique text` is present two lines ahead

  - `(?=regexp)` is a lookahead feature, won't be part of matched text

Comment: thanks that works, there is now a possibility that there will be text/html code between each block of unique colour/string code but but for some reason the perl command doesn't change the colour when i have that?

Comment: do you mean there are multiple matches? add `g` flag after the last `/` in the command..

Answer (score 1):

If the input is valid xml and `xmlstarlet` is available, the following could be used to update the class attribute of all li elements which contain "More unique text":

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//li[contains(.,"More unique text")]/@class' -v 'orange' file
```